# Use peg or operative revision syntax for SVN externals?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

When configuring properties for an external entity in Subversion there is the option to refer to the entity with [peg or operative revision number](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html).

For example when including "bar" within repository "foo", found on the same server as our current working copy, we can use one of these definitions:

```
^/foo/bar@123 bar     # peg revision
-r 123 ^/foo/bar bar  # operative revision
```

I understand the difference between peg and operative revisions in general. Which syntax would be the preferred one when defining an external in Subversion?